# PHP Three column table from database of products

Tags: php, loops, foreach

Just wondering if someone could give me a hand with a cheeky php for each loop...

I currently have a table of products which i have echo'd out to a table each with a 75% < hr > afterwards but i'd like it to become a Three column table. I don't mind if for example there are 4 products in the table of products and its in the first column and the next 2 are empty etc

Current Code as below...

```
<?php

if($results && mysql_num_rows($results) > 0){
?>

  <?php
    $i = 1;
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)){
        $i++;
?><table width="750">
<tr>
    <td id="topbottom" width="220px"><a href="products.php?id=<?php echo($row['productId']); ?>"/><img src="images/<?php echo($row['imageName']); ?>"  width="220px"/></a></td>
    <td id="pad">
    <h1><?php echo($row['productName']); ?></h1>
    <br>
    <h2><?php echo($row['productType']); ?></h2>
    <br>
    <h3> &pound;<?php echo($row['productPrice']); ?></h3>
    <br>
    <?php echo($row['productDesc']); ?>
    <br /><br />
    <a href="products.php?id=<?php echo($row['productId']); ?>"/><img src="images/findout.png"/></a>

    </td>
  </tr></table><hr color="#6c3600" width="75%" />
<?php
    }
?>  


<?php
} else {
    echo("<p>No items found</p>");
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<table width="750">

<?php

if($results && mysql_num_rows($results) > 0){
?>

  <?php
    $i = 0; // Set this to 0, since php is 0 based
    $cols = 3; // Number of cols you want
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)){
        // Use the modulus operator to see if i is an even multiple of $cols
        // If it is then we need to open a new table row
        if($i % $cols == 0) 
        {
            echo '<tr>';
        }    
?>
    <td id="topbottom" width="220px"><a href="products.php?id=<?php echo($row['productId']); ?>"/><img src="images/<?php echo($row['imageName']); ?>"  width="220px"/></a></td>
    <td id="pad">
    <h1><?php echo($row['productName']); ?></h1>
    <br>
    <h2><?php echo($row['productType']); ?></h2>
    <br>
    <h3> &pound;<?php echo($row['productPrice']); ?></h3>
    <br>
    <?php echo($row['productDesc']); ?>
    <br /><br />
    <a href="products.php?id=<?php echo($row['productId']); ?>"/><img src="images/findout.png"/></a>

    </td>
    <?php

    $i++;
    // Same as above but we want to close the table row after $cols
    if($i % $cols == 0) 
    {
        echo '</tr>';
    }
    ?>
<?php
    }
?>  

</table><hr color="#6c3600" width="75%" />


<?php
} else {
    echo("<p>No items found</p>");
}
?>
```

Key things to look for:

Set `$i` to `0` since php uses 0 based arrays

Set up a var called `$cols` which allows you to change the number of columns easily

Used the `%` (modulus) operator to find if a number is an even multiple of columns to dynamically add the `<tr>` tags in the correct places.

Comment: Worked like a dream.
Thanks Brombomb!